# How to compute distances with both categorical and continuous attributes?

Tags: clustering, distance, mixed-type-data

I have to handle with a datast containing both categorical attributes (around 25) and continuous attributes (around 25). I would like to do outliers detection. I think that it would be a good idea to cluster the observation but I don't know how to compute distances considering all the attributes, how can I do?

Comment: This is unanswerable because you don't explain what these distances are intended to represent or how you might use them.  We invite you to edit this post to include more information.

Comment: I have to handle with a datast containing both categorical attributes (around 25) and continuous attributes (around 25). I would like to do outliers detection. I think that it would be a good idea to cluster the observation but I don't know how to compute distances considering all the attributes, how can I do?